# image is not properly set in navigation controller

Tags: ios, xcode

I have written the following coding ...

[image]

```
      if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] > 4.9) {

    //iOS 5
    UIImage *toolBarIMG = [UIImage imageNamed: @"header.png"];  

    if ([self.navigationController.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)]) { 
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:toolBarIMG  
                                                      forBarMetrics:0]; 
    } else {

        //iOS 4
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar insertSubview:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"header.png"]] 
                                                               atIndex:0]; 

     }
```

Image is shown in the navigation controller but there are some pixels gap in starting and ending of the image, its showing black image. How to set image so that black color should remove. You can see pink round, i want to remove those black color..

thanks in advance.

Comment: are you having this problem in all iOS versions?

Answer (score 1):

This is how you set an image to the navigation bar

```
UINavigationBar *navBar = self.navigationController.navigationBar;
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"header.png"];
[navBar setBackgroundImage:image];
```

And put this code in the below method

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

Set Your BarMetrics to Default

```
 if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] > 4.9) {

//iOS 5
UIImage *toolBarIMG = [UIImage imageNamed: @"header.png"];  

if ([self.navigationController.navigationBar respondsToSelector:@selector(setBackgroundImage:forBarMetrics:)]) { 
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:toolBarIMG  
                                                  forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault]; 
} else {

    //iOS 4
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar insertSubview:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"header.png"]] 
                                                           atIndex:0];
```

Comment: i did the same thing and image is also showing but some pixels in starting of image and ending image showing black color ...

Comment: did u try setting the size for the image??

Comment: how can we set uiimage or background-image frame ?

Comment: UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"custom_nav_bar.png"];
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];

Comment: yes barmetrics is 0 now i change to UIBarMetricsDefault then also no difference....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20388/discussion-between-sharanya-and-bhrigesh)